# Unallocated space problem

Tags: windows-7, linux, installation, boot

I have a hp pc that has a hard drive of 750 gb and a recovery hard drive of 31gb. I installed linux side by side with windows 7 for dual booting. Now I can't boot windows 7 anymore. During the installation of linux, I chose the advanced option so as to manually partition the drives for linux. On the available list of drives, I chose the 750gb and clicked on modify. I chose 150gb for the root "/" (on ext4) and 700mb for swap out of the 750gb and clicked install. After finishing the installation I restarted the pc and sought to test linux. The linux works fine but when i tried to start windows, I have a boot error. My pc doesn't seem to recognize windows anymore. It takes me straight to the HP recovery tool. I don't understand why. So I logged into ubuntu and check the disk utility and I discovered that I have a whooping 600gb unallocated space. It's like my whole windows is gone. This is what Disk Utilty shows

```
150gb ext4    |    Free   600gb   |  RECOVERY 31GB NTFS  | HP_TOOLS 108MB FAT
```

What can I do to recover my windows back? Thanks

Comment: You can always use fixmbr ( http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927392 ), but when that is done, you'll have no access to your linux partition until you get grub installed again, so this might not be the most helpful, but may get you started in the right direction.

Comment: @MaQleod: Ok i'll try that. It's a fresh installation of linux so it isn't a big deal if the linux partition is formatted.

Comment: @MaQleod It doesn't work. It's even worse. It doesn't even go to the hp recovery anymore.  Any ideas?

Comment: Try Test Disk in an attempt to recover the windows partition, if this fails, order recovery discs from HP...http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like when you installed Linux you deleted your Windows partition and replaced it with your Linux partitions and a chunk of empty space.

You will need to assign some of that empty space to windows and reinstall windows.

There's a slim chance you may be able to get some of your data back with recovery tools, but I wouldn't hold out much hope if I were you.

I hope you took a backup of your data before installing Linux...

Answer (score 0):

Run [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk), perform a deeper search, then come back with the results.

> TestDisk is powerful free data recovery software! It was primarily designed to help recover lost partitions and/or make non-booting disks bootable again when these symptoms are caused by faulty software, certain types of viruses or human error (such as accidentally deleting a Partition Table). Partition table recovery using TestDisk is really easy.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the error happened while choosing how to partition the drive, but there is too less detailed information, to tell, what went wrong. I guess some resizing would have been needed at the beginning of the process.

For unexperienced users, it is important to have a backup before performing an ubuntu installation, because after an error, the action is often not undoable. Only a fresh windows installation, where no data has to be preserved, can be risked.

Experienced users always have a backup.